# Enforcing hashed home directory permissions with puppet

Tags: puppet, configuration-management

Home directories in our environment are hashed using the first two letters of a username.  For example, the home directory for user `lars` is `/home/l/a/lars`.

I would like to use puppet to enforce mode 0700 permissions on the user home directories, but I'm not sure how to target the home directories.  Essentially I would like to do this:

```
chmod 700 /home/*/*/*
```

In the absence of hashing this would be easy (using for example `recurse` and `recurselimit`), but the hashing has left me looking for a solution.

**UPDATE**: I am not looking to enumerate our users in puppet (because home directories are created as part of our account management process).

While thinking about this I've also become more muddled.  Even if our home directories weren't hashed, how would I get puppet to apply permissions to the *contents* of a directory without affecting the top directory itself?  I was thinking of something like this:

```
file { '/home:
  ensure => directory,
  mode => 0700,
  recurse => true,
  recurselimit => 1,
  }
```

But this would apply the mode to both `/home` and its immediate contents.  Mode 700 on `/home/lars` is fine.  Mode 700 on `/home` is a big problem.  Is this even possible?

Comment: So, basically you want to enforce permissions with puppet on directories that puppet doesn't manage? Is there any way you could make the data available to puppet? Maybe use [External Nodes] (http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/external_nodes.html) to pass an array of all the usernames or a hash appropriate to pass to the  [create_resources](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/function.html#createresources) function? Might have to cave in and write a simple shell script and call it with exec in puppet ...

Comment: I want Puppet to manage the permissions on directories that already exist, yes. That's a pretty common case, actually; you'll find that Puppet is often used to ensure file permissions and ownership on files that were not created by Puppet.

Comment: Yes, managing permissions (or other things) on files/directories that don't come from puppet is very common (I do stuff like that all the time), but managing permissions on files/directories puppet doesn't specifically know about is a whole different thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you've faced one of limitations of puppet. I'd just write a shell script that would do it.

Another possible solution might be to write a plugin for puppet which would allow you to use new datatype (say, file_wildcard) or something like that. That should be possible to write one on ruby, but I've never done that.

Comment: I will probably end up doing this with a simple shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Puppet doesn't understand wildcards in file type. If you use something like this:

```
file { "/home/*":
            ensure  => directory,
            owner   => $username,
            group   => $username,
            mode    => 700,
            require => [ User[$username], Group[$username] ]
    }
```

it will create `/home/\*` folder.

So, you must create the directory structure which you want as belows:

```
define add_user ( $fullname, $uid ) {

    $username = $title
    $firstletter = regsubst($username, '(.).*', '\1')
    $secondletter = regsubst($username, '.(.).*', '\1')

    user { $username:
            comment => "$fullname",
            home    => "/home/$firstletter/$secondletter/$username",
            shell   => "/bin/bash",
            uid     => $uid,
            require => [ File["/home/$firstletter"], File["/home/$firstletter/$secondletter"] ]
    }

    group { $username:
            gid     => $uid,
            require => User[$username]
    }

    file { "/home/$firstletter":
            ensure  => directory,
            owner   => root,
            group   => root,
            mode    => 755
    }
    file { "/home/$firstletter/$secondletter":
            ensure  => directory,
            owner   => root,
            group   => root,
            mode    => 755,
            require => File["/home/$firstletter"]
    }
    file { "/home/$firstletter/$secondletter/$username":
            ensure  => directory,
            owner   => $username,
            group   => $username,
            mode    => 700,
            require => [ File["/home/$firstletter/$secondletter"], User[$username], Group[$username] ]
    }

    file { "/home/$firstletter/$secondletter/$username/.ssh":
            ensure  => directory,
            owner   => $username,
            group   => $username,
            mode    => 700,
            require => File["/home/$firstletter/$secondletter/$username"]
    }

    # now make sure that the ssh key authorized files is around
    file { "/home/$firstletter/$secondletter/$username/.ssh/authorized_keys":
            ensure  => present,
            owner   => $username,
            group   => $username,
            mode    => 600,
            require => File["/home/$firstletter/$secondletter/$username"]
    }
}
```

and call it with:

```
node 'test_node' {
    add_user { lars:
        fullname    => "Larry Page",
        uid         => 510
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it presumes I want to enumerate
all of our users in puppet, which is absolutely not the case.  Account
creation and user management is handled through other processes.  What
I could do, I guess, is create 26 * 26 entries for `file { '/home/a/a':
}`, `file { '/home/a/b'}`, and so forth.  It's not pretty; there must
be some way to generate this without create 676 `file` entries.

Comment: OK. Your original post is not clear. "Create 26 * 26 entries" is not a good idea even when you do it with a shell script. Can you leave user creation process to Puppet handle?

Comment: You can create 26*26 entries by calling defined resource types with an array.  Something like:  `define hashhome2 ($secondletter) { file { "/home/${title}/${secondletter}": ensure  => directory,require => File["/home/${title}"]} } define hashhome () { file { "/home/${title}": ensure => directory } hashhome2 { ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']: secondletter => $title}} hashhome {['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']:}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to either declare the File resource(s) you want Puppet to manage (Puppet is a declarative language...) to puppet or your looking at using the [exec](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/2.6.8/type.html#exec) type to execute the chmod code snippet you gave.